# PROLINK WN2001 driver for LinuxMint 15

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I just installed LinuxMint 15 and have a desktop that I have installed a PROLINK WN2001 Wireless USB onto. The installation disk has only Windows drivers and now I am looking for a driver for LinuxMint 15.

Comment: These kind of investigations should be made before buying an USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research this is unlikely to work, because the official [PROLINK page](http://www.prolink2u.com/new/support/download.php?q=WN2001) only provides drivers for the Linux Kernel versions 2.6x or 2.6.18 - 2.6.38 and Kernel 3.0.2 accordingly.

Linux Mint 15 however runs a Kernel Version > 3.0.2.

I also looked up my Linux Mint (I am using v14) repository via

```
apt-cache search prolink
```

and found nothing.

Obviously you can try the newest driver from the official website and hope for the best or you can use the package `ndiswrapper` (and maybe the GUI `ndisgtk`):

```
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper ndisgtk
```

Ndiswrapper supports many wireless drivers out of the box and could therefore make your wireless card work anyway.